# Blender Geometry Nodes reference objects should be hidden

Tags: rendering, objects, geometry-nodes, collections

I'm currently experimenting with the new Geomitry Nodes in Blender and have also downloaded the Flower Scattering demo from the Blender website.

When I go to the original file, the reference objects (flowers, grass, etc.) are hidden and they are only shown distributed across the plane. The collections with the reference objects are not even displayed there. However, if I add the plane to another file, the entire collections with the reference objects are also loaded accordingly, but I cannot hide them without it disappearing from the main plane with the geometry node. It works in the viewport that the vegetation is also shown if i hide the reference objects but not in the render.

I would be really grateful for any help!

Best Regards,
Tim

Answer (score 3):

Ok i found it. All you need to do is put your collection into a collection, and make the highest collection non-rendered while keeping the baseline set to renderable.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should hide these collections using checkmark instead of your nested solution.

Comment: I think both solutions are valid, the other one has the advantage that you can still modify the contents of the source collection.